# Did not find any relation named table_name in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, unix, centos, psql

When I'm trying to list information about the table  `boarding_passes` in my schema I get an error:

```
demo=# \d boarding_passes
Did not find any relation named "boarding_passes".
```

Here is the list of all relations in my schema:

```
 demo=# \dt bookings.*
             List of relations
  Schema  |      Name       | Type  | Owner
----------+-----------------+-------+-------
 bookings | aircrafts       | table | dba
 bookings | airports        | table | dba
 bookings | boarding_passes | table | dba
 bookings | bookings        | table | dba
 bookings | flights         | table | dba
 bookings | seats           | table | dba
 bookings | ticket_flights  | table | dba
 bookings | tickets         | table | dba
(8 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `bookings` is obviously not on your `search_path`, you need to use

```
\d bookings.boarding_passes
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've just set `search_path TO bookings` to avoid entering the schema name in the future